# How to make a domain name resolve to the same IP address as another domain name?

Tags: domain-name-system, internal-dns, amazon-elb

I have a AWS ELB to the gateway of an internal service.

I have some other host names that I need to be resolved to the same address as the ELB DNS name.

In my current set up, I'm using `/etc/hosts` to manually point the names to the IP address of the ELB.

But the IP of the ELB changes once in a while and I'll have to update `/etc/hosts` again and again.

Is it possible to just tell my operating system to just resolve the specified host names as like I'm querying with the ELB DNS name?

Answer (score 0):

DNS CNAME. ELB name is the canonical name, and  the other name you want to resolve to it the alias.

/etc/hosts is not useful beyond that one host. Use DNS.

Comment: For some reason I can't change the DNS setup. My only option is to do it in your local environment.